# on Windows :command line error "cp missing destination file operand after '/usr/lib'"

Tags: makefile, shared-libraries, zlib, cp

I've been trying to install zlib using the following website to guide me [link](http://archive.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs-museum/5.1-pre1/LFS-BOOK-5.1-PRE1-HTML/chapter06/zlib.html)

and I am currently stuck in the command *make install* which is the equivalent of

```
cp libz.a /usr/lib 
cp  /usr/lib
```

which returns the error from the command prompt

```
cp: missing destination file operand after '/usr/lib' .
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
```

does anyone have any idea what is going on. I've been scratching my head for a while since libraries and stuff are real confusing.

(the zlib directory is located in C:\zlib-1.2.5 )

Comment: Looking at the output if I do a (successful) `make install`, the second copy is supposed to be something like `cp libz.so.1.2.7 <installDir>`, where `libz.so.1.2.7` is a symbolic link to `libz.so`. Did you see any previous warnings, about creating this symbolic link? Maybe that failed because the directory you build from does not support symbolic links?

Comment: are you using cygwin? or dose Windows now have a /usr/lib directory?

Comment: Can you do `cp libz.a /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.7.a` this assumes correctness of previous comment; if `libz.so.1.2.7.a` is a link to `libz.a` then `cp libz.a /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.7.a` is equivalent to `cp libz.so.1.2.7 /usr/lib`